# using svn tortoise features through code

Tags: c#, tortoisesvn

I am writing an application in c# that copies files, and I wanted to only copy files according to their tortoise-svn status.. i.e., I would like to divide the files into modified files vs unmodified.

Is there a way to do this? I've been looking at the different .exe files in the svn/bin folder, but haven't found anything. perhaps theres a dll I am overlooking?

Thanks

Comment: To be precise, the files have an svn status, rather than a TortoiseSVN status.  Tortoise SVN is a GUI and it is not the only way to work with Subversion repositories -- see the answers from @thejh and @Dialecticus.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to `svn` directly, use `svn status`.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.tour.cycle.examine.status

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for your help, it finally works... I got it to work using two methods:

either using a process in c# and calling the SubWCRev.exe (if you put in as a process argument the path of the file you want to check for svn modifications, you should get that detail as an output).

and the other way was adding the SubWCRevCOM.exe as a reference and then using it as so:

```
using LibSubWCRev;
SubWCRev subCheckMod = new SubWCRev();
subCheckMod.GetWCInfo(@file_to_check, true, true);
if (subCheckMod.HasModifications) {...}
```

thanks again everyone =]

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is tagged as C#, I would suggest looking for .Net bindings to subversion.

[SharpSvn](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) looks like it would meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

[TortoiseProc](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html) is used for automation, but you need to study its syntax.

Comment: That page says: "Remember that TortoiseSVN is a GUI client, and this automation guide shows you how to make the TortoiseSVN dialogs appear to collect user input. If you want to write a script which requires no input, you should use the official Subversion command line client instead."

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use the exes that come with TortoiseSVN look at `SubWCRev.exe`.